# How to divide request in loop controller between ThreadsGroups jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have some problem with time of invocation of requests.
The following structure of test plan :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl1tX.png
I read directly ulr path from txt file and send it
my code

```
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/tidaltv/LogsReplayer/LoggerReplaySTG_AllRegions/InputData/test.txt")));
String line = null;
int count = 0;

while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] values = line.split(" ");
  for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    if(values[i].startsWith("/ILogger.aspx?"))
    {
      props.put("path_" + count, values[i]);
      log.info(props.get("path_" + count).toString());
    }
  }


  count++;
}
props.put("LoopCounterValue", count.toString());
props.put("CounterValue", (count-1).toString());
log.info(count.toString());
lineReader.close();
```

but when i execute my test plan in one thread, for example, 20000 request its take much time.
Can i divide requests between several threads to make its faster

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in the normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and writing the values to JMeter Properties just switch to the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) and write the values to the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

This way you will be able to use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and specify the desired number of threads in the Thread Group so the requests would go in parallel and each JMeter thread (virtual user) would fetch the next value from the CSV file on each iteration.